# javascript not executing in html

Tags: javascript, html

I'm using the Google javascript function to try to make a pie chart. It works fine as a fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/qb8av4td/.

But when I copy it into my own webpage, it doesn't work. I'll I'm doing is adding `<script type="text/javascript">` and `</script>` around the javascript section. It's easier if I can put both of the two script sections in the body, but I've tried the conventional head/body approach as well, and I can't get it to execute. The problem is the same on two browsers, and java is working elsewhere on my site. What have I done to prevent it from executing here? Thanks!

```
<html>
<head>

 <script type="text/javascript">

      google.setOnLoadCallback(drawChart);
      function drawChart() {

        var data = google.visualization.arrayToDataTable([
          ['Truth or Falsity', 'Judgment!'],
          ['True',     28],
          ['False',     8],
          ['Partly True, Partly False',  69],
          ['N/A', 13],
        ]);

        var options = {
          title: 'The True Science of "Ithaca"'
        };

        var chart = new google.visualization.PieChart(document.getElementById('piechart'));

        chart.draw(data, options);
      }

      </script>

</head>
<body>

<script type="text/javascript" src="https://www.google.com/jsapi?autoload={'modules':[{'name':'visualization','version':'1','packages':['corechart']}]}"></script>
       <div id="piechart" style="width: 400px; height: 300px;"></div>

 </body>
 </html>
```

Comment: Are there any errors in your developer tools? Which browsers are you using?

Comment: are you loading the js in the same order as in the fiddle? Open console (hit f12 in your browser, reload the page), do you see any errors? The google.com script tag needs to load first then you can execute your script.

Comment: You need to add the script to external resources and then click in head instead of in body http://jsfiddle.net/mplungjan/n9r0unnh/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you have the wrong order

you must first include the google script library

and then call functions of it

so first :

```
 <script type="text/javascript" src="https://www.google.com/jsapi?autoload={'modules':[{'name':'visualization','version':'1','packages':['corechart']}]}"></script>
```

and then :

```
<script type="text/javascript">

  google.setOnLoadCallback(drawChart);
  function drawChart() {

    var data = google.visualization.arrayToDataTable([
      ['Truth or Falsity', 'Judgment!'],
      ['True',     28],
      ['False',     8],
      ['Partly True, Partly False',  69],
      ['N/A', 13],
    ]);

    var options = {
      title: 'The True Science of "Ithaca"'
    };

    var chart = new google.visualization.PieChart(document.getElementById('piechart'));

    chart.draw(data, options);
  }

  </script>
```

so its upto you to put it in head or body, only important thing is to load the library before you execute functions included in the library,

best approach for my opinion is to put both right before the closing body tag

```
  script library
  script your script depending on library
</body
```

Answer (score 1):

You need to place your JavaScript *after* the Google JavaScript library.

Answer (score 1):

You are calling `google.setOnLoadCallback` in the first script element, but you don't define it first. Presumably that is handled by the second script element. You need to define `google` before you try to call methods on it.

Answer (score 1):

You need to load the Google JS *before* your own JS

Answer (score 1):

I would guess it's because you're running the line:

```
google.setOnLoadCallback(drawChart);
```

*before* you've actually loaded the script:

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="https://www.google.com/jsapi?autoload={'modules':[{'name':'visualization','version':'1','packages':['corechart']}]}"></script>
```

At the time your code runs, `google` is `undefined`.  You'll want to move the `<script>` tag up to the top of the head, above your code.